# Is there a way to get a separate desktop for each user logged in through VNC?

Tags: user-accounts, vnc, remote-access, vncserver

Hi I am accessing my desktop remotely through VNC server/client connection.

I used [Vino](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#vino) to establish a remote connection. Now the app which I am building requires provision of a different section in which number of users can log in the machine at the same time.

Also each of the users should have a fresh instance. Is there any existing application that serves the purpose or should I make the users login through different ports of vnc (like 5900 for first user and 5901 for next n so on)?

Comment: What OS is the VNC server running? I assumed Linux due to the Vino (Ubuntu) reference. Hence, the 'possible dupe' link is for Linux.

Comment: @techie007 : thanks for your help hope the link tutorial do work let me try this . :)